# Get PC specifications from user in PHP

Tags: php

Probably not possible, but can I get the computer specifications (GPU type, amount of RAM, etc.) from an user on my website?

Comment: We all hope this is _not_ possible, since that would be a mile wide privacy and security issue.

Comment: No, php runs on your server, not the clients machine so it does not have access to this information. Javascript can access a scary amount of data: https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2 about a user, but probably not that kind of hardware spec. To truly spy on your users like that, you need to have them install something

Comment: More like those sites like canirunit.com, but they use an extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the only information about the user's system you'll be able to access in PHP is in the HTTP user-agent string, via `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`. But that can be spoofed, so shouldn't be considered 100% reliable.

Assuming it's correct, you'll generally be able to determine a user's browser and operating system, but nothing about the hardware itself (I guess you can tell if it's 32- or 64-bit). An example would be something like

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36
```

As mentioned in a comment, Javascript can access additional information such as screen resolution so you would be able to record that via an AJAX request or similar, but I'm still not aware of a way to detect anything about the CPU or GPU specs.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with PHP alone (that's server side scripting).